# CodeIgniter upload file error: you did not select a file to upload

Tags: codeigniter, upload, codeigniter-2, filesize

This question has been asked before, but not with this exact issue.
I have an upload system that works great (I'm uploading CSV and parsing them).
However, if a file size is over 5Mb it gives me the error:
you did not select a file to upload

If it is under, the file uploads and parses just fine.

I've set my php.ini setting first to 128M and just now to 99999999999999999999
I've also set my CI config maz_size to 9999999999
(I was using more realistic numbers, but I wanted to be sure)
I've restarted apache with each ini change but still ths problem remains.

I've seen that the error:
you did not select a file to upload 
is shown when there's a file size issue but I don't know where else to check this.

Finally, if I echo phpinfo(), I can confirm that max upload is 999999999999999

Pulling my hair out...

What else could it be?

/// update: code addition
I've got two methods of parsing the csv, either line by line or dumping the whole file direct into the DB and sort it out later. both of these work, and are selected by a config setting. that's what the line: $this->config->item('import_type') is for. Any ideas are welcome!

```
    public function upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|csv|xls|xlsx';
    $config['max_size'] = '999999999999999999999';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('feed_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        if ($this->config->item('import_type') == 'db') {
            $result = $this->model_feed->capture_file($this->input->post('feed_name'), $data['upload_data']['full_path']);
        } else {
            $result = $this->capture_feeds($this->input->post('feed_name'), $data['upload_data']['full_path']);
        }

        if ($result) {
            $this->load->view('feed_upload_success', $data);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('feed_form', array('error' => 'The file you supplied does not match the data structure we were expecting.' ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set your form to be multipart?

Comment: can you paste your code? Perhaps there is a typo or something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to increase post_max_size on php.ini too

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: Yip, did that.. it's currently at 9999999999999

Comment: I lied... (sorry..) It was indeed the post-max-size solution.
I read your reply to quickly and thought it said maxupload etc..
thank you SOOO much... I've added this to my check list of things to um, check. next time I do a similar job.

Comment: have been betrayed by that config many times too...
memory_limit, max_execution_time, all of them can cause problems in upload...

Answer (score 0):

i had a same problem and what i did is on `$this->upload->do_upload()` function i have passed the name of the input file i mean from the form input type file name. Suppose i gave the name as avatar so i used the function as `$this->upload->do_upload('avatar')`